# Recursion in wget with outside directories

Tags: recursion, wget, archive

I have a list of links. Those links each have a small list of text files that I'm trying to archive.

My list is at host/file/list.html

The list has almost a thousand links to /file/list.html?id=xxx

Inside of the list.html?id page, the linked files are located at /data/file/list/filename.txt with filename not having any patterns other than the filetype.

Along the way are all the header and footer links that I want to ignore. If I set my include-directories to /data/file/list it won't scrape any pages that are /file/list.html?id=xxx

Here's what I've got so far, but it won't work with recursion l=2, I have to be on the id page itself to work.

```
wget --recursive -l 2 --include-directories=/data/file/list http://host/file/list.html
```

This only downloads list.html and stops. If I also include /file/list it downloads too many other files, I'm only looking to download as few files as I can. I realize it's going to have to read each of the list.html?id pages to get the txt file lists, but it looks like its downloading all of the id pages one at a time without going through the links. Just in case I had my recursion limit wrong, I tried l=3 but that had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the code adding /file/list to the included directories, also adding -nc to help prevent downloading the same header, footer links multiple times. It seemed to have worked well, mostly downloading the necessary files.